# Accept handler for Boost ASIO async

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

So I am trying to write a class using Boost ASIO to send data asynch. over a TCP socket.

My cpp file

```
#include <TcpServer.h>
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

TcpServer::TcpServer(unsigned short port = 1700)
: ipPort(port){
io_service svc;  
tcp::socket socket(svc);
tcp::acceptor acc(svc, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), ipPort));
acc.listen();
acc.async_accept(socket, TcpServer::Accept_Handler);
 boost::thread bt(boost::bind(&io_service::run, &svc));
}

void TcpServer::Write_Handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec){
  if (!ec)
    {
     std::cout << "Just sent some %0.2f" << yawData << std::endl;
    }
}

 void TcpServer::Accept_Handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec){
   if (!ec)
     {
      async_write(socket, buffer("data"), TcpServer::Write_Handler);
    }
}

void UpdateYaw(double data) {
   yawData = data;
```

}

```
  TcpServer::~TcpServer(){
    svc.stop();
 }
```

And its header

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>


 class TcpServer {
  private:
   double yawData = 0;
   unsigned short ipPort;
   void Write_Handler(const boost::system::error_code&);
   void Accept_Handler(const boost::system::error_code&);
  public:
   TcpServer(unsigned short );
   void UpdateYaw(double);
   ~TcpServer();
  };
```

The error I get at compilation is

```
 no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::async_accept(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’acc.async_accept(socket, TcpServer::Accept_Handler);
```

It simply doesnt like the handler that I pass as an argument to `async_accept`. Ofcourse this happens to the other handler (Write_handler) as well at `async_write`. 
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::bind(&TcpServer::Accept_Handler, this, std::placeholder::_1). And  doublecheck write handler signature